# Update visual styling of dynamically added checkbox in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm currently adding a bunch of checkboxes dynamically during the "pageinit" event, which I am able to both add and check successfully. The checkboxes are added by appending instances of the following stub to a "ul"-component:

```
<li>
<div class = "new-student">
    <img class="profile-img nav-ui-thumbnail ui-mini" src="../images/prof_img.gif">
    <!-- Block A -->
    <div id="grid" class="ui-grid-a ui-mini">
        <div class="ui-block-a ui-mini">
            <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-mini">
                <h2 class="name-student">Name</h2>
                <p class="attendingtime-student">00:00</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Block B -->
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-mini">
                <h2 class="pickuptype-student">null</h2>
                <p class="pickuptime-student">00:00</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form>
        <!-- Attending -->
        <fieldset class="fieldset ui-overlay-shadow" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="localnav">
            <input class="attendance0-student" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-h-2a">1</label>
            <input class="attendance1-student" name="checkbox-h-2b" id="checkbox-h-2b" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-h-2b">2</label>
            <input class="attendance2-student" name="checkbox-h-2c" id="checkbox-h-2c" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-h-2c">3</label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

However; I am unable to update the visual styling of the checkboxes, which result in all checked boxes looking like this:

[image: Incorrectly displayed checkboxes]

I've tried calling ".checkboxradio.('refresh')" but it only results in an error (saying I can't call that method on a component that has yet to be initialized).

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding this:

> I've tried calling ".checkboxradio.('refresh')" but it only results in
>   an error (saying I can't call that method on a component that has yet
>   to be initialized).

Usually when this kind of error occurs you need to do this:

```
$('#someId').checkboxradio.().checkboxradio.('refresh');
```

First call will initialize checkboxradio widget and second one will enhance its markup.
But this is not case with checkbox widget, to enhance dynamically added checkbox you need to do this:

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio();
```

Without refresh parameter.

And here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/VAG6F/77/

There are of course other solutions, read [**this**](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/) article if you are using older versions of jQuery Mobile up to 1.4 (mentioned functions are currently deprecated).

If you are using jQuery Mobile 1.4 and you are planing in using future versions then use this method:

```
$('.ui-content').enhanceWithin();
```

Read more about it **[here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)**.

There's a third option, instead of **pageinit** use **pagecreate** event. Like **pageinit** it will trigger only once but unlike **pageinit** it triggers before jQuery Mobile enhances active page. So everything appended at this point will automatically become enhanced.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Gajotres! Unfortunately none of the methods you posted seem to do the trick in my application. :(

Comment: Come on, I gave you a working example, it should work. Can you add your javascript, at lease part where you are appending new content, including document ready if you are using it.

Comment: Also are you using page events in your application?

Comment: I am using page events, but the problem is that the application is built around a single page that opens new pages using Ajax, which in turn append components based on the contents of a database. So the page events seem to only affect the "index.html".

New pages are "opened" using this function:
http://pastebin.com/DrhLWwmF

Comment: Why would that be a problem? Can you at least create a jsFiddle example out of your code and I will fix it for you? I hope you understand that without your code this question is unanswerable.

Comment: The problem is that it's a pretty big project, so creating a jsFiddle would be kind of difficult. A lot of dependencies and stuff.. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54136/discussion-between-cethy-and-gajotres).